# How to pick the gradient color?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, colors, gradient

I know little bit about color picking software and web based programs. But I want to pick the color and exact gradient pattern.

Is it possible to do so ? For example I want the exact gradient for my circles in MS Powerpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Color Picker**

In PowerPoint 2013 and above you have the `Eyedropper` tool which allows you to pick the color from an image/shape/etc. (example below)

[image]

In earlier versions of Powerpoint you don't have this option, but you can use another software that will tell you the color code. In PowerPoint you can only use the RGB color code, so if you have a HTML or Pantone code you can google for an online converter (e.g. HTML to RGB).

---

**Copy Gradient/Style**

If you already have a shape with a gradient in PowerPoint and would like to copy that exact gradient to another shape you can use the `Format Painter` tool. (image below)

For images is harder to reproduce the exact gradient. You can use a color picker to get the base colors and after just struggle to match that gradient. :)

[image]

Comment: I am familiar with Eyedropper feature but it won't help me with gradient. Format Painter would help me if both of the shapes are designed in Powerpoint, isn't it? I guess otherwise, It's not so helpful when I want to replicate something exactly from different source.